# FIX Protocol 4.4 Connection not responding to Login

Tags: authentication, fix-protocol

To anyone who can help,

I am having a show stopping issue connecting to the test server.

My TCP/IP connection is established via:

Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

I send the connection message to the server via:

_socket.Send(_txData);

where _txData is a byte[] _txData array initialized with the connection request message:

8=FIX.4.4\0019=121\00135=A\00149=NotRealSenderID\0 0156=NotRealTargetID\00134=1\00152=20140522-20:12:04.392\00198=0\001108=30\001554=NotRealPassw ord\00110=017\001 converted to a byte array.

I wait for the login success message via:

int responseCount = _socket.Receive(_rxBuffer);

but after a few seconds, the _socket.Receive unblocks and returns zero bytes suggesting unsuccessful connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Is my login message at fault? Is it the way I establish server connection? I am at a loss!

Currently, My default Windows 7 Firewall is disabled, and I attempted to telnet into the server, and the image below snapshots the outcome:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, as this is a major show stopper for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue. The problem was with the SOH character in my message.

I was using the literal SOH = "\001" converted to a byte, when I should have done this: SOH = (char) 0x1; DUH!!

For the record, I used the following tools to 'debug' this issue:

Wireshark with display filter and capture filter set to the host server's ip address, and MINI-FIX to generate and transmit FIX messages to the host server.

I then compared the output from my client to those produced by MINI-FIX via Wireshark. It didn't take me long to spot the error from there.

Comment: How to type `0x1` SOH in telnet?

Comment: Append \x to the beginning of the byte. e.g. "\x01".

Comment: Replace SOH with \x01? Like this?`8=FIX.4.4\x019=103\x0135=A\x0149=Q142\x0156=XCD1\x0134=240\x0152=20171009-03:26:20\x0198=0\x01108=30\x01553=primexm_hgnh_uat_1_q\x01554=tVN84Y93THc5\x0110=253\x01`, seems not work.

Answer (score 0):

What is "the test server" ?
Can you ping it ?

From the look of that telnet session you haven't permission to make a connection, or there is nothing running at the destination.

Comment: Problem has been resolved. See the above. Thanks for your help, tho.